# How to find all rows having common dates on different party

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe in which I want to extract only those rows which have common dates (skipping time part of datetime) among different Party .

Example Dataframe :

| Party | Date & Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-10-01 8:30:40 |
| A | 2021-10-01 9:45:40 |
| A | 2021-10-01 10:50:40 |
| A | 2021-10-02 7:30:40 |
| A | 2021-10-02 7:30:40 |
| B | 2021-10-01 8:30:40 |
| B | 2021-10-01 8:30:40 |
| B | 2021-10-05 8:25:40 |
| C | 2021-10-01 6:10:40 |
| C | 2021-10-05 10:25:30 |

Output I want :
In Input Dataframe  A,B and C party have common date 2021-10-01 and B,C party have common date 2021-10-05 .I want all these rows irrespective of different times.

| Party | Date & Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-10-01 8:30:40 |
| A | 2021-10-01 9:45:40 |
| A | 2021-10-01 10:50:40 |
| B | 2021-10-01 8:30:40 |
| B | 2021-10-01 8:30:40 |
| B | 2021-10-05 8:25:30 |
| C | 2021-10-01 6:10:40 |
| C | 2021-10-05 10:25:30 |

The code I tried :

```
df.loc[df['Date & Time'].dt.date.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

but it includes dates that are only found in same Party too. I want all the rows that have common dates among different Parties.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the `Party` column by `date` then `transform` with `nunique` to count the number of `unique` parties then keep the rows which have unique count `>= 2`

```
d = df['Date & Time'].dt.date
df[df.groupby(d)['Party'].transform('nunique').ge(2)]
```

---

```
  Party         Date & Time
0     A 2021-10-01 08:30:40
1     A 2021-10-01 09:45:40
2     A 2021-10-01 10:50:40
5     B 2021-10-01 08:30:40
6     B 2021-10-01 08:30:40
7     B 2021-10-05 08:25:40
8     C 2021-10-01 06:10:40
9     C 2021-10-05 10:25:30
```

Comment: Now . how can we  further filter  all rows having common dates and common hour skipping minutes and seconds

Comment: Change `df['Date & Time'].dt.date` to `df['Date & Time'].dt.floor('H')`